# How to access telerik ajax radgrid values in the controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax, telerik

I am new to using Telerik and asp.net.
The application I'm trying to build uses telerik ajax controls in asp.net MVC2 application.
I have used a Telerik RadGrid of Ajax in my view of the mvc2 application as follows:

```
    <form runat="server" id="form1" method="post">   

<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">   

</telerik:RadScriptManager>  

<h2>Index</h2>  


<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server"    

DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="None"    

AllowMultiRowSelection="True" Skin="Web20" AutoGenerateColumns="False">   

<MasterTableView DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowFilteringByColumn="True"    

DataKeyNames="Val1">   


<CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to Pdf"></CommandItemSettings>  

<RowIndicatorColumn>  

<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>  

</RowIndicatorColumn>  

<ExpandCollapseColumn>  

<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>  

</ExpandCollapseColumn>  

<Columns>  

<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Val1" HeaderText="Val1"    

SortExpression="Val1" UniqueName="Val1">   

</telerik:GridBoundColumn>  

<telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Val2" HeaderText="Val2" ReadOnly="True"    

SortExpression="Val2" UniqueName="Val2">   

</telerik:GridBoundColumn>  


</Columns>  

</MasterTableView>  

<ClientSettings ActiveRowIndex="0" AllowKeyboardNavigation="True" >  

<Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />  

</ClientSettings>  

</telerik:RadGrid>  




<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"    

ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SomeConnectionString %>"    

SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [someTable]"></asp:SqlDataSource>  


<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>   





</form>
```

I want to access the selected values from the RadGrid in my controller(atleast the key value). How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,
Hilda

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you can do that using the SelectedItems collection of the grid, then fetch the key values from the selected rows from there as done [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdretrieveprimarykeyfieldvaluesforitems.html).

Still if you rely on the pure MVC concept, think about switching the telerik ajax grid with [their mvc grid extension](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx) which is pure mvc component.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend switching from Ajax to MVC versions unless you want to step off the rainbow. The MVC version of the Grid is pale in comparison. I'm not sure if they're working on beefing the MVC grid up, but there are less than half of the features ported over.